# Sent Json to REST API - Access Control Allow Origin [ERROR]

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, vue.js, xmlhttprequest

I want to send a json to my REST API. i tried it with Postman and it works fine. Now i want to sent Data from my frontend. I dont know where i need to add the header and how i do it. Im using Springboot for my BackEnd and Vue for my FrontEnd.
My Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class FileController {

FileService fileService;

public FileController(FileService fileService) {
    this.fileService = fileService;
}

@RequestMapping(
        value = "/data",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = "application/json")
public void process(@RequestBody String payload) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(payload);

    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(...);
        writer.write(payload);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

My main.js, which shall send the data:

```
const toSend ={

"name": "test",
"test1":"test2"
 };

const jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend);

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8090/api/auth/data");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(jsonString);
console.log(jsonString)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable cors for this controller.
There is an annotaion for that matter.
Check out this guide
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that sending by xhr is best solution? why don't you use fetch?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Yours vue app and spring boot apps runs on different ports and browser sees it separate websites that why it blocks because of cors. Other solution that adding cors headers, can be proxy on js side.

Comment: Im not sure yet. I cant use fetch in IE. Maybe ajax is a thing